# JS function formating currency

Tags: javascript

Good morning folks. I just started to learn JS and got a task in which I am stuck. I need to change number format to have 2 decimal places and it should also start with pound sign.

```js
function formatCurrency() {
    var formated = formated.toFixed(2);
    return formated;
}

function calculateSalesTax(price: number) {
    return price * 0.21;
}

const product = "You don't know JS";
const price = 19.99;
const salesTax = calculateSalesTax(price);

console.log("Product: " + product);
console.log("Price: " + formatCurrency(price));
console.log("Sales tax: " + formatCurrency(salesTax));
console.log("Total: " + formatCurrency(price + salesTax));
```

When I tried to shorten numbers it throws me an error.Could you please point me in correct direction, as it looks like a very simple task.

Comment: Your `formatCurrency` need a parameter

Comment: function formatCurrency(number) {
    var formated = number.toFixed(2);
    return formated;
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
function formatCurrency(price) {
  var formated = price.toFixed(2);
  return formated;
}

function calculateSalesTax(price) {
  return price * 0.21;
}

const product = "You don't know JS";
const price = 19.99;
const salesTax = calculateSalesTax(price);

console.log("Product: " + product);
console.log("Price: " + formatCurrency(price));
console.log("Sales tax: " + formatCurrency(salesTax));
console.log("Total: " + formatCurrency(price + salesTax));
```

The `formatCurrency` function needs to accept an argument (the price) passed into it and use that in the formatting.
The `calculateSalesTax` function shouldn't have the type definition added to the argument (this is fine in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#typing-the-function)).

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to add parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your correct code:

```
function formatCurrency(price) {
    return `\u00A3 ${price.toFixed(2)}`;
}

function calculateSalesTax(price) {
  return price * 0.21;
}

const product = "You don't know JS";
const price = 19.99;
const salesTax = calculateSalesTax(price);

console.log("Product: " + product);
console.log("Price: " + formatCurrency(price));
console.log("Sales tax: " + formatCurrency(salesTax));
console.log("Total: " + formatCurrency(price + salesTax));
```

You were not declaring an argument for formatCurrency. \u00A3 is the code for the pound sign, as putting £ will result in a bad behaviour in js. The backticks (``) allows you to use "literal", go search for it, it is a useful tool in javascript. Also, you attempted to declare a return type for calculateSalexTaxPrice, which you can not since typing is possibile in TypeScript only

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about parameter =). Now everything is working.